# Problems with conditional cell formatting for table in R-Markdown (Quarto)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am creating an R-Markdown (Quarto) document for bean aggregation. I have a table within the document and I would like one of the columns (Progress) to have conditional highlighting depending on the cell value (RED if less than 30, GREEN if greater than 70, ORANGE otherwise).

The R-Markdown code is as below (I don't know how to reprex R-Markdown code):

````html
---
title: "delete later"
author: "Tumaini"
format: pdf
editor: visual
---

## Aggregated beans stock

The intention is that the **progress column** is color-coded depending on the value of the cell. It should be **red** if less than 30%, orange between 30% and 70% and green if above 70%

```{r, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)

beans_stock = tibble::tribble(
   ~`Data Entry`, ~District,           ~Ward,             ~AMCOS, ~`Bean Stock (MT)`, ~`Target (MT)`, ~Progress,
  "2022-03-30",  "Kasulu",    "Nyakitonto",       "Nyakitonto",               94.3,           330L,       29L,
  "2022-03-29",  "Kasulu",     "Nyachenda",          "Twikome",               63.3,           202L,       31L,
  "2022-03-29", "Kibondo",      "Kitahana",         "Kitahana",               48.3,            88L,       55L,
  "2022-03-29",  "Kasulu",     "Nyachenda",         "Motomoto",               44.8,           152L,       29L,
  "2022-03-29",  "Kasulu",      "Kitagata",          "Ubhumwe",               37.6,           123L,       31L,
  "2022-03-30", "Kakonko",    "Kiziguzigu",       "Kiziguzigu",               34.4,           410L,        8L,
  "2022-03-29", "Kibondo", "Kibondo-Mjini",    "Kibondo-Mjini",               17.3,           140L,       12L,
  "2022-03-26", "Kibondo",      "Kitahana",             "Ruti",                6.9,           210L,        3L,
  "2022-03-29", "Kibondo",      "Bunyambo", "Kibondo-Bunyambo",                  4,           140L,        3L,
  "2022-03-17", "Kibondo",      "Kitahana",             "Ruti",                0.6,           210L,        0L
  )



```

```{r}
beans_stock %>% 
  mutate(
    Progress = kableExtra::cell_spec(
      Progress, background = ifelse(Progress > 70,"green",
                                    ifelse(Progress < 30,"red","orange")))
  ) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable(escape = FALSE,format = "latex") %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling("striped", full_width = T)

```
````

However this is not working, can anyone point to what I might be doing wrong? The intention is to render to PDF.

Comment: @Maël yes, sorry for that, I did indeed mean Quarto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change from `background` to `color` as the argument in `cell_spec()` your code works as expected.

If you want a colored background, you need to remove the last line of code `kableExtra::kable_styling("striped", full_width = T)`.

If you want full width, you need to adjust latex options in `kable_styling`:

```
beans_stock %>% 
  mutate(
    Progress = kableExtra::cell_spec(
      Progress, background = ifelse(Progress > 70,"green",
                                    ifelse(Progress < 30,"red","orange")))
  ) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable(escape = FALSE,format = "latex", booktabs = T) %>% 
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options="scale_down")
```